# Can Uber be forced to limit its "dynamic prices" policy?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy

After recent attacks in London, [many complained about the prices rising in the vicinity of the attacks](http://www.snopes.com/uber-increase-london-attack/):

> There is no dispute that Uber prices were elevated in London around
>   the time of the attack, which police say started just after 10 P.M.
>   local time. This is because the company uses a system called “dynamic
>   pricing”, which increases or decreases the price of a journey based on
>   algorithms that analyze the intensity and volume of demand for Uber
>   cars in a given geographical area.

From an oversimplified point of view, if the demand for its services increases very much within a time frame, raising the prices seem like a natural thing to happen as the offer cannot satisfy the demand.

Practically, severely limiting the price does not mean that more clients will get a drive, only that the fastest to book (first-come, first-served). So, all late callers will have a denial of service.

**Question: Can Uber be forced to limit or even not use its dynamic pricing algorithm?**

Comment: Are you asking from a political or a legal point of view?

Comment: @origimbo - from a political point of view, mostly. Limiting the prices seems like great interference from authorities.

Comment: Trivially, yes, it can be done... that is the whole point of the government being able to enact and enforce laws... maybe am I missing something?

Comment: @SJuan76 - technically, it is possible, but isn't this against the free market or something similar to do so?

Comment: This is isn't a completely free market to begin with. Private vehicle hire in London is already a regulated market for customer service and public safety reasons. https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/taxis-and-private-hire/new-private-hire-regulations?intcmp=40503

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [the principle of parliamentary sovereignty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_sovereignty_in_the_United_Kingdom), the UK parliament can create laws about pretty much everything, including fixing prices. So theoretically they could do that. Whether or not they *should* and how such a law could be worded in detail is a question for a more discussion-oriented website.

Comment: There could be international treaties that prevent them from doing so? EU treaties for example (UK will still be an EU member for the coming ~1.5 years), as well as possibly others.